# Which file mode to choose and creating lists in a loop

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, dictionary

back again with another problem. I am trying to make a "table maker" - for now just creating files with dictionaries and checking keys.

I have two problems: firstly i don't know if there is a file format for writing in binary but not overwriting a previous file if it already exists? I tried the (try, except) method but the excepted FileExistsError does never come up :/ (in the createTable function)

Secondly I have a problem with creating lists. I made a loop which asks for entries and values for them to be stored in separate lists. Those lists will later be zipped into a dictionary and pickled into a file. (in the createTable function)

Of course if there are other mistakes I'd love them pointed out :)

```
import pickle

def checkTable(nameOfTable) :

    try :
        #seeing what is it they are looking for
        prompt = input("What do you want to check?\n")
        with open("%s.pkl" % nameOfTable, "rb") as f:
            data = pickle.load(f)
            #getting what they want from the data from table
            whatTheyWant = data.get(prompt, "There is nothing like that in the table.\n")
            print(whatTheyWant)
    #if table doesn't exist
    except IOError as e:
        print("Sorry such a directory doesn't exist.\n")


def createTable(nameOfYourTable) :
    try :
        #opens a new file with the table
        with open("%s.pkl" %nameOfYourTable, "wb+") as f :
            decision = "yes"
            if decision == "yes" :
                #asking for entries and keys to put into the table
                #creates lists with entries and values to be zipped together
                entry.append = input("What is the entry?\n")
                value.append = input("What is the value of the entry?\n")
                decision = input("Do you want to go on? (yes/no)\n")
                i += 1
            else :
            #getting it all into a dictionary and putting it into a file
                table={dict(zip(entry, value))}
                pickle.dump(table, f)
    #if a file with the name already exists
    except FileExistsError as e :
        print("Sorry, a file with this name already exists.")


#what the person wants to do
answer = input("Hello. Do you want to create a table or check an existing one?\n")

#asking for the name of the new table
if answer == "create" :
    nameOfYourTable = input("What do you want the table to be called?\n")
    createTable(nameOfYourTable)
#asking what table to look in
elif answer == "check" :
    nameOfTable = input("What is the name of the table?\n")
    checkTable(nameOfTable)
else :
    print("\nThat's not a valid option.\n")

print("Thank you for using me. It was very nice.")
```

Comment: You can't arbitrarily add data to a file that contains a pickle, that would make no sense. But you should consider using a different file format anyway; your dict contains just strings, a text serialization format like JSON would be far more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file mode just for what you want, `open(file, "x")`, add `b` or `t` as per your need.

**In `x` mode a file is created only when it *does not* already exist**, raises exception otherwise. The `createTable` function does not really make sense to me. `decision = "yes"` then `if decision == "yes":`? `decision` is supposed to be a `global`? It's very fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pickle read the list from the file first, add to the list, and then write a new pickle file at the end. Btw, you can check if a file exists with `os.path.exists`. Appending items to a list is done with `list_name.append(new_item)`. You need to have initialized the list first with `list_name = []`.